# Hikari connection pool exhausted

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hikaricp

I have spring boot application which use hikari pool to create connection pool.
we are using postgres sql for db. when I hit the system with low qps the request takes around 200 ms to execute. When One pod is deployed and the qps is 15 things remain in good state. but as soon as I increase the qps to 20 the request starts taking ~10 sec to process and connection pool becomes empty(
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: phoenix - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30183ms).

I am using this configuration.

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=200
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=50
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=0
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=30000
spring.datasource.TYPE=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold=10000
```

The pod cpu usage goes max till 30% and memory usage is also under control. I am using an aws hosted postgress which can have 10000 parallel connection to the db.
Can someone please help me here?

Comment: You have to check which postgres configuration you are using (i.e. 2 vCore CPU, 8 vCore CPUs etc.). Because this configuration also help you understand why your connections are getting exhausted. Mostly it has nothing to do with Hikari CP.

Comment: It has 32 cpu cores and cpu usage doesn't go more than 4%.
We are firing 3 query per connection and as the qps increasing the query execution time starts to increase

Comment: it is db.m6g.8xlarge instance of RDS

Comment: As you mentioned, you have increased qps to 20 & requests took 10 secs. 10 secs is leak detection & timeout value in your code , meaning query execution would have timeout or logged leak detection error .     Also, your max pool size is 200 means 20 * 10= 200 is eventually got used as soon as you increase qps.  Since your vCore CPU is 32 (Max allowed connections are 1495 in this case), so you can try to increase max pool size to somewhat 500 & see if you still getting this kind of exception

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful when setting Hikari props like pool size and minimum idle. Increasing those values doesn't necessarily mean that you will get better throughputs or performance outcomes.
Please check this.
https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing